# JFace TreeViewer, setting the element on top programatically

Tags: tree, element, jface, treeviewer

I have spent hours and didn't find the solution for something which for me seems natural operation:
How can I force the TreeViewer to show in the visiple part of the Tree a given element?
In other words, how can I scroll it to the point where the first element to visualize is one specific?

```
_______________
A
 B
 C
_______________

And I want to visualize B as the first element:
_______________
 B
 C

_______________
(So the tree is scrolled down, programatically).
```

I would really appreciate some help in here.
Thanks a lot in advance :)

---

Thankis greg,
but setInput, doesn't change the root? What I want is not to set the root to B, which result in the example would be:

```
__________
B
```

***_*___**
    (B on the top-left and its children hanging).

But to show the B element on top (not top-left), so the equivalent to scrolling it up or down.
In other words, I don't want to change the model, I want to apply the view to show other part of the model.

Answer (score 0):

Call `TreeViewer.setInput` specifying the list of second level elements rather than the top level element (and make sure your content provider `getElements` method understands this).

If you are using this in Eclipse you can use `org.eclipse.ui.part.DrillDownComposite` which adds 'go into', 'back' and 'home' buttons which use the `setInput` method to change the root (used in the New / File wizard for example).

Comment: Thankis greg,
but setInput, doesn't change the root? What I want is not to set the root to B, which result in the example would be:

    __________
    B
    __________
    (B on the top-left and its children hanging).

But to show the B element on top (not top-left), so the equivalent to scrolling it up or down.
In other words, I don't want to change the model, I want to apply the view to show other part of the model.

Comment: The only things that may scroll the tree are `setSelection(xxx, true)` or `showItem(TreeItem)` but they only make sure the item is visible.

Comment: Thanks greg,
yes, I was aware about this approach and I think that I will try that: first get it visible and then scroll down the view till it becomes the first of the list...
It was just surprising that there is not a direct way: for me it makes more sense than the make visible -wherever-.
Thanks again! Now that I got your answer I feel I am not doing it completely wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, someone gave me the solution in other forum:
http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1123124/.

Basically is the use of setTopItem.
More details in the other thread.